# Why does ("bar"):find("(foo)?bar") return nil?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Shouldn't `("bar"):find("(foo)?bar")` return `1, 3`?

`print(("bar"):find("(foo)*bar"))` and `print(("bar"):find("(foo)-bar"))` won't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because parentheses in Lua's patterns (quite unfortunately) do not serve as a grouping construct, only as a delimiters of capturing groups. When you write a pattern `(foo)?bar`, Lua interprets it as "match `f`,`o`,`o`,`?`,`b`,`a`,`r`, capture `foo` in a group". Here is a [link to a demo](http://ideone.com/IMBbEW). Unfortunately, the closest you can get to the behavior that you wanted is `f?o?o?bar` , which of course would also match `fbar` and `oobar`, among other wrong captures.

this code

```
print(("bar"):find("f?o?o?bar"))
```

[returns 1 3](http://ideone.com/TBLtgw)

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for string `"(foo)bar"` or `"(foobar"` from string `"bar"`, the questionmark `?` only points to the last character.

If you want it to point to the whole word, use `[]` instead: `("bar"):find("[foo]?bar")`

Comment: `"(foo)?bar"` is supposed to be a pattern, where `"foo"` can appear 0 to 1 time and `"bar"` is always supposed to appear. Applied to the `"bar"` string it should logically return the position of `"bar"` but it returns `nil`.

Comment: @Morhaus Right, check my complete edit. Such a long time since I've been coding lua, didn't remember the pattern matching anymore.

Comment: The thing with `[foo]` is that it will match either `"f"` or `"o"`, but I'm trying to match whether `"foobar"` or `"bar"`.

Comment: @Morhaus Then I'm out of ideas. But I'm sure it can be done somehow

Comment: you'll probably have to use two different expressions to do the capture, unfortunately. lua's pattern matching grammar aren't regexs.